# How can I eliminate this duplicated "git diff" call in a while loop?

Tags: bash, while-loop

How can this code construct be optimized to avoid duplicate code (`git diff --ignore-space-at-eol -U0`)?

```
while [ ! -z "$(git diff --ignore-space-at-eol -U0)" ]; do
  diff_text=$(git diff --ignore-space-at-eol -U0);
  echo $diff_text
done
```

In PHP it could be done like this:

```
while (! $diff_text = "git diff --ignore-space-at-eol -U0") {
  echo $diff_text;
}
```

We need code so that the `diff_text` variable is subtracted 1 time.

Comment: why dont you preassign it before the loop?

Comment: Assumedly, the output will  potentially change on each iteration (due to something that's not in the question)

Comment: at each iteration, the data may be different, so not before the loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can insert multiple instructions inside the while condition block:

```sh
while
  diff_text=$(git diff --ignore-space-at-eol -U0)
  [ -n "$diff_text" ]
do
  echo "$diff_text"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an infinite loop with a break condition to add commands before the comparison that breaks the loop:

```
while true; do
   i=$(date)
   echo $i
   [[ "$i" =~ "9 " ]] && break
   sleep 1
done
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a function that sets the `diff_text` variable, and returns non-zero if it is empty:

```
function set_diff_text
{
    diff_text=$(git diff --ignore-space-at-eol -U0)

    [[ -n $diff_text ]] && return 0 || return 1
}

while set_diff_text; do
    printf '%s\n' "$diff_text"
done
```

Another way to use a function to do it is:

```
function get_diff_text
{
    local difftxt
    difftxt=$(git diff --ignore-space-at-eol -U0)
    printf '%s\n' "$difftxt"

    [[ -n $difftxt ]] && return 0 || return 1
}

while diff_text=$(get_diff_text); do
    printf '%s\n' "$diff_text"
done
```

- See the accepted, and excellent, answer to [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/264812) for an explanation of why I used `printf` instead of `echo` to print the `git diff` output.